# In LangChain, how to save the verbose output to a variable?

Tags: agent, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I tried executing a langchain agent. I want to save the output from verbose into a variable, but all I can access from the agent.run is only the final answer.

How can I save the verbose output to a variable so that I can use later?

My code:

```py
import json
from langchain.agents import load_tools
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent
from langchain.agents import AgentType
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.agents import Tool
from langchain.utilities import PythonREPL

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.1)

## Define Tools
python_repl = PythonREPL()

tools = load_tools(["python_repl", "llm-math"], llm=llm)

agent = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True)

response = agent.run("What is 3^2. Use calculator to solve.")
```

I tried accessing the response from the agent, but it's only the final answer instead of the verbose output.

printing response gives only 9. But I would like the verbose process like:

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
 I need to use the calculator to solve this.
Action: Calculator
Action Input: 3^2
Observation: Answer: 9
Thought: I now know the final answer.
Final Answer: 9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't find any API to save verbose output as a variable.

However, I think an alternative solution to the question can be achieved by access intermediate steps in this [link](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/agents/agent_executors/examples/intermediate_steps.html).

That is set `return_intermediate_steps=True`,

```py
agent = initialize_agent(
  tools, 
  llm,
  agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, 
  verbose=True,
  return_intermediate_steps=True
)
```

and use `response = agent({"input":"What is 3^2. Use calculator to solve"})` instead of `agent.run`.

Finally, you can access the intermediate steps in  `response["intermediate_steps"]`

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks. This gets the verbose process indedd, though I guess I'll have to format the intermediate steps myself.

Comment: also, `response["output"]` has the string final answer!

Comment: @Tyler2P I have a doubt, how can we store intermediate steps as ai message in memory (ConversationBufferMemory) If the intermediate steps value is json/dict and not a string. Thanks in advance